# Creating polygon mask in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, visualisation, masking

In QGIS 3.22.5, is there possible to use polygons for the masking layer?
I want to use numerous little polygons to mask lines (only layer which consists of lines).

In ArcGIS that works just by clicking the layers you want to use in "appearance -> masking".

For example in QGIS: labels can be created as masks which work fine.

[image: f]

[image]

I hope that picture in above explain what I'm looking for.
Polygon (red) masking lines (black) and result is in right side picture.

Comment: If you create your "masking" polygons in their own layer, symbolize them as white with no outline and have that layer just above your lines layer in the layers panel, they should block seeing the lines.

Answer (score 7):

In QGIS version 3.24, it is now possible to mask layers using other layers. It is necessary to create a group of layers, where the mask layer and the masked layer will be located.

1. In the layers panel, select a group and enable the "Render layers as a group" option for it:
   [image]
2. In the layers panel, select the mask layer and set the appropriate blending mode for it:
   [image]

It's done! https://qgis.org/ru/site/forusers/visualchangelog324/index.html#feature-rendering-layers-as-groups

**EDIT:**
To mask a **raster layer**, there must be two vector layers in the group. One vector layer is a mask. The second vector layer is any other (even empty).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Difference](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference) tool:

> Extracts features from the input layer that don’t fall within the
> boundaries of the overlay layer.