# Is it possible to mask raster layer with vector layer on the fly in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to mask a raster layer (only visually) kind of on-the-fly just with styling layer attributes, such that layers below become visible in masked regions?

Assuming we have 3 layers:

- `VectorLayer` (polygons)
- `RasterLayer`
- `AnyLayer` (e.g. background imagery)

In QGIS we have a bunch of styling options which are quite versatile, e.g. we can use the "Inverted polygons"-style with the `VectorLayer` and set the fill color to black. In the mapview we can now see the `RasterLayer` everywhere where there is no `VectorLayer` polygon. I would consider this as on-the-fly masking already.

But is it also possible to not just overpaint these areas outside the polygons but make them transparent? The goal here is that the lower layer (`AnyLayer`) should become visible where `RasterLayer` is masked by `VectorLayer`. It might be possible e.g. with some combination of color blending mode, but not sure.

Comment: Is layer transparency what you are looking for?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/435489/109118  Note, for some reason, to mask a raster layer, there must be two vector layers in the group. One vector layer is a mask. The second vector layer is any other (even empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Group VectorLayer and RasterLayer.
2. activate the group styling option `Render layers as a group` in the Layer Styling Panel of the group
3. Set Blending Mode of VectorLayer to `Mask below`. This option becomes available after step 2.

(described at [Creating polygon mask in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432427/creating-polygon-mask-in-qgis/435489#435489))

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a workaround, but still technically "clipping on  the fly".

One way is to use the GDAL Warp processing tool with some additional parameters to specify a cutline and alpha band. You can output to a virtual raster VRT (small XML text file) that references the original raster and the vector.

Additional parameters:

```
-cutline /path/to/vectors -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good solution, however I went with Blending Mode `Mask below`, which becomes available once you set the group styling in the Layer Styling Panel to "Render layers as a group", as mentioned in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432427/creating-polygon-mask-in-qgis/435489#435489